# How to delete an entry from an array using submit button(php)

Tags: php, arrays

The codes below displays the entries of the of variable $a thru foreach loop with a remove button on its end as shown below..
[Please click here to see the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDs7m.png)

But when I clicked the remove button of the first entry the system deleted the last entry. Please help me fix this. Thank you.

```
    $a = $new_batch_marketing->query("SELECT * FROM temporary_container");  

            if(empty($a)){
                #do nothing
            }
            else{
                echo '<table style="width: 400px; height: 400px; resize:none;color:black;background:white;"readonly = "readonly">';
                foreach($a as $key){
                    $z = $key['product_code'];
                    echo '<tr><td>'.$key['product_name'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$key['product_type'].'</td>';
                    echo'<td>'.$key['selling_price'].'</td>';
                    echo'<td>'.$key['case'].'</td>';
                    echo'<td>'.$key['total_selling_price'].'</td><td><input type = "submit" name = "remove" id = "'.$z.'" class =  "form-control" value ="remove" style = "width:60%;"></td></tr>';
                }
                echo '</table>';

                echo'</br></br><input style = "width: 99%;border-radius:2px;" type = "submit" id = "confirm" name = "confirm" value = "confirm" class = "form-control"></br>
                    <input style = "width: 99%;border-radius:2px;" type = "submit" id = "cancel" name = "cancel" value = "cancel" class = "form-control">';

                if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
                        $remove = $new_batch_marketing->query("DELETE FROM temporary_container WHERE `product_code` = '$z'");
                    }
            }
```

Comment: why do you want to do it via POST when you can get it done using GET. As far as security is concerned, have a check on server side if the user is allowed to perform that operation or not.

Comment: Just a hint, you will need to render a form and will have to add the id in hidden field..

Comment: In `DELETE` query you use `$z` when you should be using product_code as returned in `$_POST`

Comment: Be care, your code has a lot of security problems.

Comment: You had to rework on : your $z variable is initialized with the last productCode. If you want to do this, you had to pass the right product code in the post query. can you dump your $_POST  when you submit the remove button

Comment: Actually, it seems that your code isn't even returning product_code in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

```
$a = $new_batch_marketing->query("SELECT * FROM temporary_container");  

            if(empty($a)){
                #do nothing
            }
            else{
                echo '<table style="width: 400px; height: 400px; resize:none;color:black;background:white;"readonly = "readonly">';
                foreach($a as $key){
                    $z = $key['product_code'];
                    echo '<tr><td>'.$key['product_name'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$key['product_type'].'</td>';
                    echo'<td>'.$key['selling_price'].'</td>';
                    echo'<td>'.$key['case'].'</td>';
                    echo'<td>'.$key['total_selling_price'].'</td>
                    <td><a href="?remove='.$z.'"<input type = "button" name = "remove" id = "" class =  "form-control" value ="remove" style = "width:60%;"></a></td>
                    </tr>';
                }
                echo '</table>';

                echo'</br></br><input style = "width: 99%;border-radius:2px;" type = "submit" id = "confirm" name = "confirm" value = "confirm" class = "form-control"></br>
                    <input style = "width: 99%;border-radius:2px;" type = "submit" id = "cancel" name = "cancel" value = "cancel" class = "form-control">';

                if(isset($_GET['remove'])){
                        $remove = $new_batch_marketing->query("DELETE FROM temporary_container WHERE `product_code` = '$z'");
                    }
            }
```

Comment: It still delete the last entry of the array.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Replace this  if(isset($_GET['remove'])){
                        $remove = $new_batch_marketing->query("DELETE FROM temporary_container WHERE `product_code` = '"$_GET['remove']"' ");
                    }

Comment: That's not cool bro. I write a code for you and you didn't marked it correct.

Comment: I apologize. I lost my internet connection.

Comment: One more thing, I wonder why is the spacing between values within each line entry is to short while spacing after every line entry is a bit high. I hope you can help me on that. Again, thanks a lot. @ Sunny Sharma